# How to speed up the OpenGL (viewport) rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, opengl

I made an animation in ***Cycles*** (about 1 minute long) using ***viewport render*** option (Render-->***OpenGL Render Animation***). There were some simple objects like hearts (with basic diffuse colour) and planes with a photo textures. It rendered in about 8 minutes. 
[image]

Then I simplifed the scene: reduced the vertex count, and enabled the simplify option. The rendertime was about 2 minutes this time.
[image]

My goal is to render the animation in about 1 minute. Do you know any tricks to reduce the rendertime a bit more? Are there some settings I missed?

Comment: instanced objets maybe. duplicate hearts with alt+D

Comment: Samples.... unless you didn't want to lose video quality. or you know... just get a better PC. :)

Comment: @Bithur I think instances made with [alt]+[D] don't act as normal instances-they still take time to render.

Comment: I've found that cutting down the number of light sources helps speed things up quite a bit. Also, is that a window on the right side. I've found that transparent materials basically double the render time of the areas that they cover.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. @A Radish- Brilliant idea :) @Francisco Chavez-Tejeda- thanks for the great idea with light sources. I'll try to bake them as a color texture.

Comment: @Gonzou maybe you can put the techniques you have used as answer

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would like to state that OpenGL viewport rendering has nothing to do with Cycles rendering.

Speed of OpenGL viewport rendering depends heavily on your GPU and in some cases (particle/physics/modifier heavy scenes) also on your CPU. There are certain borders that GPU can't get across whatever the setting may be.

Here are two solutions that might help you though, altough I am not certain what kind of result are you looking for. Both are diminishing the actual result but the speedup is considerable in certain situations.

---

Disabling the Anti-Aliasing would improve the speed of the OpenGL rendering greatly.

[image]

---

You may also think about using Bounding boxes only, if you are trying camera movement or animating a lot of objects and you want to see how their general location and rotation change over time.

[image]